# The UV editor shows that there's no stretching but my UV grid is still stretched

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I'm pretty new to UV, so I think that I'm missing something simple. I've been stuck trying to texture this wall for almost a week now and for some reason even though the UV editor says that there's no stretching (all blue), the UV grid and any image texture I apply seem to be super stretched and sometimes even upside down or rotated weirdly. please help.
[image: example]

here's my project, I didn't pack any textures since they're unnecessary. [image]

Comment: Did you smart uv-unwrap? It looks like, that your UVs are not the same format as your Objects Faces. You could try to Unwrap it with a different unwrap methode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]